# Power function - assigning indexes

Tags: javascript, recursion

Working on "Higher, Lower" function in codeacademy. 
can someone please explain why we are using the same argument to invoke the same function inside of the guessMyNumber function?

I was under the impression that I needed to decrement or increment the argument.

Please see the code below.

```js
function guessNumber(number) {
  // Prompt the user for a number
  guess = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 100");

  // Convert their guess to a number using +
  guess = +guess;

  // Define base case
  if (guess == number) {
    return console.log("You got it! The number was " + number);
  }
  // Define recursive case with a function call
  if (guess < number) {
    console.log("Higher");
    guessNumber(number);
  } else {
   console.log("Lower");
   guessNumber(number); 
  }
}

// Call the function guessNumber() with an integer for an argument
guessNumber(5);
```

Comment: Because the number you're trying to guess doesn't change.

Comment: you're using the same argument because the point of the game is to determine an unknown yet unchanging number through an iterative guessing scheme

Comment: @oldrinb i̶t̶e̶r̶a̶t̶i̶v̶e̶  _recursive_

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the game is one of [iteration](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration) regardless of whether the implementation is recursive